# Getting the daily sales report given the date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a date, the table displays the items sold on that date.

The table groups the category of the items and show the total sales value for each category. At the end, the report shows the total sales value for the day(s). Something like this:

```
ID    Category  Price   Units   Total Value
----------------------------------------------------
2244    class   10.50    10       105.00   
2555    class   5.00      5       25.00   
3455    class   20.00     1       20.00   

  Total                  16       150.00    

1255    pop     20.00     5       100.00
5666    pop     10.00    10       100.00

  Total                  15       200,00

1244    rock    2.50     20       50.00   
8844    rock    5.00     50       250.00   

  Total                  70       300.00

----------------------------------------------

Total Daily     Sales   101       650.00
```

DBMS: SQL Server 2012

Bolded: primary keys

Item (**upc**, title*, type, category, company, year, price, stock)
PurchaseItem (**receiptId**,  **upc**, quantity)
Order (**receiptId**, date, cid, card#, expiryDate, expectedDate, deliveredDate)

```
Rough work of what I have so far..

SELECT I.upc, I.category, I.price, P.quantity, P.quantity*I.price AS totalValue, SUM(totalValue), SUM(P.quantity) AS totalUnits, O.date
FROM Item I, Order O
JOIN (SELECT P.quantity
      FROM PurchaseItem P, Item I
      WHERE I.upc = P.upc)
ON I.upc = P.upc
WHERE O.date = ({$date}) AND O.receiptId = P.receiptId
GROUP BY I.upc, I.category, I.price, P.quantity, totalValue, O.date
```

Alright, this isn't right and I'm kind of stuck. Need some help!
I want it so it produces the total value of items from one category then in the end, it will add up the total value of the items from all categories.

***SAMPLE TABLES***
Item(2568, Beatles, rock, Music Inc, 1998, 50.50, 5000)
PurchaseItem (5300, 2568, 2)
Order (5300, 10/09/2014, ...Not important..) cid is customerId and card# is credit card number.

Comment: Could you provide sample data for each table?

Comment: Item(2568, Beatles, rock, Music Inc, 1998, 50.50, 5000)      
PurchaseItem (5300, 2568, 2)   
Order (5300, 10/09/2014, ...Not important..)
cid is customerId and card# is credit card number.

Comment: It'll be better to include the data you used in the question. Also, edit the question when you include the sample data.

Comment: At least include more data. How can we test the sum if we only got one row?

Comment: I think you need `group by with rollup` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

SSRS or a similar reporting package can usually handles this for you natively.  If this has to be done in SQl script then a quick solution would be a cursor/while loop.  pseudo code would look like this;

```
create tempsales table;
get distinct list of categories;

for each category
Begin
  insert into tempsale (...)
  sales where category = @category 
  group by category, item

  insert into tempsales (...) -- use NULL value for item or perhaps a value of 'TOTAL'
  Sales where category = @category
  group by category

  when last category 
  insert into tempsales (...) -- use NULL value for item AND Category or perhaps a value of 'TOTAL'
  total with no group
end

 select from tempsales;
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

**CREATE SAMPLE DATA**

```
use tempdb;

create table Item(
    upc         int,
    category    varchar(100),
    price       decimal(8,2)
)
create table PurchaseItem(
    receiptId   int,
    upc         int,
    quantity    int
)
create table [Order](
    receiptId   int,
    [date]      date
)

insert into Item values
(2244, 'class', 10.50),
(2555, 'class', 5.0),
(3455, 'class', 20.0),
(1255, 'pop', 20.0),
(5666, 'pop', 10.0),
(1244, 'rock', 2.50),
(8844, 'rock', 5.0)

insert into PurchaseItem values
(5300, 2244, 10),
(5300, 2555, 5),
(5300, 3455, 1),
(5300, 1255, 5),
(5300, 5666, 10),
(5300, 1244, 20),
(5300, 8844, 50)

insert into [Order] values(5300,'20140910')
```

**SOLUTION**

```
;with cte as(
    select
        i.upc as Id,
        i.category as Category,
        i.price as Price,
        p.quantity as Units,
        price * quantity as TotalValue
    from [Order] o
    inner join PurchaseItem p
        on p.receiptId = o.receiptId
    inner join Item i
        on i.upc = p.upc
)
select
    Id,
    case
        when grouping(Id) = 1 then 'Total'
        else Category
    end as Category,
    Price,
    sum(Units) as Units,
    sum(TotalValue) as TotalValue
from cte
group by 
    grouping sets(Category, (Category, Id, Price, Units, TotalValue))
union all
select
    null,
    'Total Daily Sales',
    null,
    sum(Units),
    sum(Totalvalue)
from cte
```

**DROP SAMPLE DATA**

```
drop table item
drop table PurchaseItem
drop table [Order]
```